# How to add a new object to an array of objects in localStorage?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, input, local-storage

Initially there is an array (persons) of objects in localStorage.
When entering data into the input, a new object must be formed, and when you click save, this object must be added to the array(persons) of objects in the localStorage.
But the setItem method removes previous objects. How add new objects to the old ones in the localeStorage?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please check this out first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve the array from local storage, add the new object to it, then store it back in local storage.

```
var persons = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("persons") || "[]");
persons.push(new_person);
localStorage.setItem("persons", JSON.stringify(persons));
```

Comment: Old objects disappear, only the new object remains in the localStorage. After updating the page, the old ones return, and the new one disappears.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the call to JSON.stringify